# Index length for varchar column in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, ddl

In MySQL we can set the length of the field that will be indexed this way:

```
CREATE INDEX part_of_name ON customer (name(10));
```

Can we do the same in PostgreSQL? If yes, then how?

Comment: I wonder if 'prefix' indexing is as nearly-useless in Postgres as in MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data type allows modifying the length, the syntax is close:

```
create index part_of_name on customer((customer_name::varchar(10)));
```

[Here is an example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b2Kw4K62H2aAreLyUpi6EH/0) how this index can be used; you have to use the same type cast in the condition.

and for the `text` I assume @Mureinik suggestion is the only option. Effectively the index with the cast is expression based index anyway, so my answer is kind of same, but with closer to the OP syntax.

Comment: The answer is kind of incomplete without instructions how the index can be used.

Comment: I created the fiddle with exact usage sample - do you think I should explicitly mention that you have to use same expression?..

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of a way to do this directly, but Postgres supports indexes on expressions, so you can get the same behavior by indexing a `substring` call:

```
CREATE INDEX part_of_name ON customer (SUBSTRING(customer_name FOR 10));
```

Comment: The answer is kind of incomplete without instructions how the index can be used.